# Libgdx setup UI gives 2 unexpected errors in new GWT project

Tags: android, gwt, android-emulator, libgdx

I have run the setup ui, however, I get two different errors in the -html project than what is described in the tutorial: [libgdx tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=pOYrtJwYaGw#!)

The tutorial error stated is as follows (which is an error I do not see):

> To fix the error of the HTML5/GWT project, go to the "Problems" view, right click the error message "The GWT SDK JAR gwt-servlet.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory" and select "Quick Fix". Click "Finish".

The errors I have are:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project   ...

> The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Is there anyway i can fix this? I just updated my eclipse, I also downloaded Version 18 ADT, revision 19 for Android SDK Tools, and revision 11 for Android SDK Platform-tools.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago and got around it by installing the [GWT SDK](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download).

Comment: hmm.. i downloaded the plugin in eclipse for it. http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6 ... would this work? Is this what you did? If you downloaded the zip, did you add the entire folder into your project? Thanks for your help

Comment: I installed the plug-in, and all of the optional components that came with it. The link you gave was for Eclipse 3.6. I'm using 3.7 so it's possible that there may be some subtle differences.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after installing GWT 2.6 eclipse plugin. Not able to find the GWT in 'Add library' options. Any clues how to add it in the build settings?

Answer (score 1):

I know that the post is old, but while the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971341/624341) of @Rod was close to resolve my problem, it didn't fully. After installing the plugin in his answer I got 3 error messages instead of two: the same previous ones and a new one.

Looking inside the class that was giving the problem made Eclipse to point straight to the problem: the compiler compliance required to be 1.5 or greater but Eclipse had by default 1.4. I changed it through **Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level**, where I put the correct one, 1.7, and everything compiled cleanly.

PS: Thanks @Rod

Answer (score 0):

use the **http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2** to install plugin on eclipse

instead of http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/**4.4 or 4.3**