# Errors when setting up a LibGDX project

Tags: java, android, libgdx

After I import my project into eclipse I get lots of errors from the android, html and the robovm projects.
The errors i get are :

```
the hierarchy of the type `ClassName` is inconsistent.
```

`ClassName` is the class name of my android, html and the robovm projects. 
how can I fix it? I searched in google but didnt find any solutions.

Comment: Firstly import the desktop application and run it. When it works, you need to add some android libraries for android. (Step by step ) I have imported so many libgdx android project, but all of these were not working. Check some samples on this address. https://github.com/tugrulasikcom/libgdx

Comment: Try cleaning the projects and maybe reimport and close Eclipse. Should resolve everything but the GWT projects (at least for me it does)

Comment: Still doesn't work.. but somehow the desktop and the core projects are working, but the rest doesn't work.. so I am using only the desktop and the core projects for now ( i dont plan to develop for android and ios anyways)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't install the necessary plugins. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971110/libgdx-setup-ui-gives-2-unexpected-errors-in-new-gwt-project) for the GWT plugin. You will also need to install the ADT plugin for Android ([see this](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)).

This is a necessity and if it still doesn't help, sometimes cleaning the projects, reimporting and restarting helps.