# Libgdx game making tutorial (Drop) Iterator<Rectangle>

Tags: java, libgdx

So i'm very new to libgdx and i were doing the drop tutorial that is at the libgdx wiki.So when i finished i got an error on line 98 at `Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();`
More specifically it says :

> The type HTMLDocument.iterator is not genetic; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments `<Rectangle>`

Also in the console i get this :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Rectangle>
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Rectangle>
at com.mygdx.test.Test.render(Test.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I really dont know why i get this error if you know the solution i would really appreciated help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you accidentally added a wrong import!

You need to import:

```
 import java.util.Iterator;
```

Instead of:

```
 import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;
```

because the class `HTMLDocument.Iterator` is **not used at all** in the [libgdx drop tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)

Comment: YES!!!It seem to finally work!!Many thank man i were searching for a fix for like a month now you can't believe how gratefull i am!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the html project not automatically being set up properly. Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971110/libgdx-setup-ui-gives-2-unexpected-errors-in-new-gwt-project)